# Binding events with jQuery to multiple elements with a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, bind

So I'm working on this think where I need to generate elements and then bind events to them. Every time I generate an element I unbind and rebind the events to the generated elements with a for loop. These functions seem to trigger, but they get the wrong index (which tells the code which element to work with).

Check out the code at jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6UgYe/4/

Anything modular that solves this will do. Also feel free to comment on my code. I wrote most of this last year when I had just begun with javascript.

Regards,

Akke

EDIT: Here is the solution in action: http://jsfiddle.net/nwH8Z/3/ it calculates VAT-Free prices on blur.

Comment: If you [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) your event handlers, then you won't have to unbind and rebind them everytime you modify the DOM.

Comment: the problem is that you reuse the Id `box` over and over, you should make this a class. Also, as said above, use `$.delegate()` (for versions before 1.6, `$.live()` for 1.6, or `$.on()` for 1.7 and above.

Comment: All right, sounds good. I'll test those things and report back.

Comment: you can also bind elements only when it's needed... like $(elem).mousenter(function(){//bind it})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `bindEmAll` function to look like this -

```
function bindEmAll()
{
    $('#container').on('blur', 'input[id$=".5"]', function(){

     $('#Errorfield').append('Current box is ' + this.id + '<br/>').append(num_format(this.value) + '<br />')  

})
}
```

It makes all input boxes with IDs that end in '.5' append their ids and values, handled by your `num_format()` function, to `#Errorfield`. The event handler is attached to ***all*** input boxes inside `#container`, even if they are added dynamically.

And remove `bindEmAll()` from your click handler for `#addTT`; otherwise the event handlers will be bound as many times as you've clicked addTT, which makes things quite messy ;-)

```
$('#addTT').click(function() {
    addTT('#container');
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6UgYe/11/).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Would it be more appropriate to just add the code to $(function(){}) instead of into bindEmAll() since it binds to elements created in the future also?

Comment: You can put it where you like, as long as it fires when you want it to. I'd keep it in the named function, because it would make the code more maintainable IMO.

Comment: Thank you, Jasper. I'll put it in a named function, and add a call to it inside of my startup $(function(){})!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening because the `blur` event handler is not being run until well after the loop finished.  The order of execution is:

- Attach event handler to blur event on item 1
- Attach event handler to blur event on item 2

...some time later...

- Actually invoke the blur event

By the time your event handler is invoked the value of the variable `i` from the loop has changed to the index of the last value, so that is what is being used in the event handler.

To get around this you can just put your code inside a closure:

```
 (function(i) {
        $('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').unbind();
        $('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').blur(function() {
            //error processing function;
            $('#Errorfield').append('Current box is $(\'#container input#box' + i + '\\.5\')<br />');

        });
        $('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').blur(function() {
            $('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').val(num_format($('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').val()));
            $('#Errorfield').append('Current box is $(\'#container input#box' + i + '\\.5\')<br />');
        });
    })(i);
```

I've updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/6UgYe/10/)

Comment: It's easier and simpler to use `.on()` to create the event handler for all elements within `#container', as per my answer.

Comment: All right! This seems to work. +1 for explaining what actually was happening. Even though your solution _works_ Jasper Moggs answer seems more appropriate and oprimized, so I'm considering it over this. Nevertheless, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  boxes = 1;

        function num_format(input) {
            //For demo purporses, we only parseInt()+5
            ret = parseFloat(input) + 5;
            return ret;
        }

        function addTT(parentElement, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5) {

            if (!arg1) {
                arg1 = "";
            }
            if (!arg2) {
                arg2 = "";
            }
            if (!arg3) {
                arg3 = "";
            }
            if (!arg4) {
                arg4 = "";
            }
            if (!arg5) {
                arg5 = num_format((0.00).toFixed(2));
            }


            row = $('<tr></tr>').attr('id', boxes);

            cell1 = $('<td class="inputcell"></td>');
            cell2 = $('<td class="inputcell"></td>');
            cell3 = $('<td class="inputcell"></td>');
            cell4 = $('<td class="inputcell"></td>');
            cell5 = $('<td class="inputcell"></td>');

            input1 = $('<input></input>').attr('style', 'width:100px;').attr('id', 'box' + boxes + '.1').attr('name', 'box' + boxes + '_1').attr('type', 'text').attr('value', arg1);
            input2 = $('<input></input>').attr('style', 'width:100px;').attr('id', 'box' + boxes + '.2').attr('name', 'box' + boxes + '_2').attr('type', 'text').attr('value', arg2);
            input3 = $('<input></input>').attr('style', 'width:93px;').attr('id', 'box' + boxes + '.3').attr('name', 'box' + boxes + '_3').attr('type', 'text').attr('value', arg3);
            input4 = $('<input></input>').attr('style', 'width:149px;').attr('id', 'box' + boxes + '.4').attr('name', 'box' + boxes + '_4').attr('type', 'text').attr('value', arg4);
            input5 = $('<input></input>').attr('style', 'width:90px;').attr('id', 'box' + boxes + '.5').attr('name', 'box' + boxes + '_5').attr('type', 'text').attr('value', arg5);

            $(cell1).append(input1);
            $(cell2).append(input2);
            $(cell3).append(input3);
            $(cell4).append(input4);
            $(cell5).append(input5);

            $(row).append(cell1);
            $(row).append(cell2);
            $(row).append(cell3);
            $(row).append(cell4);
            $(row).append(cell5);

            $('#tBoxes').append(row);
            boxes++;
        }

        function subTT(parentElement) {
            boxes = boxes - 1;
            $(parentElement + ' #' + boxes).hide(0, function () {
                $(parentElement + ' #' + boxes).remove();
            }
            );
        }
        function bindEmAll() {
            alert(boxes);
            for (var i = 1; i <= boxes - 1; i++) {

                $('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').blur(function () {
                    alert($(this).val());
                    $(this).val(num_format($(this).val()));
                    //$('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').val(num_format($('#container input#box' + i + '\\.5').val()));
                    //$('#Errorfield').append('Current box is $(\'#container input#box' + i + '\\.5\')<br />');
                });
            }
        }
        $('#addTT').click(function () {
            addTT('#container');
            bindEmAll();
        });
        $('#subTT').click(function () {
            subTT('#container');
        });
        $(function () { addTT('#container'); bindEmAll(); });
```

Comment: inside bindemAll i have changed only blur function

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of adding new elements and process their events:

```
<button id="add">+</button>
<button id="remove">-</button>
<div id="holder">

</div>
```

.

```
$('#add').on('click', function () {
    $('#holder').append('<p>click me!</p>');
});

$('#remove').on('click', function () {
    $('#holder p:last-of-type').remove();
});

$('#holder').on('click', 'p', function () {
    alert('my id is: ' + $('#holder p').index(this));
});
```

And you can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/simo/PyKDz/

Comment: This is a good generalised example. See my answer for a specific solution to this question.